# VBA - Error to get the number of workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with counting the right number of opened workbooks.

Concretely, I have a big excel file with my database. I have other data (sports results) from a software, and I export them. So I have my database opened, and dozens of other workbooks ("`Workbook1`", "`Workbook2`", ...), with one workbook per tournament.

My final goal is to loop workbook by workbook to `copy/paste` the data in my database.
But when I use `MsgBox(workbooks.counts)`, it only returns "`1`".

Do you have any idea why ? What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: how many workbooks were opened when you run this ?

Comment: If its not a typo in question, it should be `MsgBox(workbooks.count)` not `counts`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `For Each wb in Application.Workbooks....Next` loop so it doesn't matter how many you have open, it will loop through them all.  It could also depend on if all the workbooks were opened in the same Excel instance, or separate ones. If you have an `Excel.exe` process for each workbook (check Task Manager), then each workbook is open in its own "copy" of Excel, which will give you a count of 1 workbook (in the instance).

Comment: Thanks you both for you answers ! Indeed I did not though about the fact that there were several instances. My code now works, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested but I took some code from the web many moons ago (apologies, I don't have the reference any more) and modified it for the purposes of acquiring all workbooks in all Excel instances.

It may be of use to you or others. APIs are declared for 32 bit so you'll have to modify them if necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
    ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim bks As Collection

    Set bks = GetAllWorkbooks
    MsgBox bks.Count
End Sub

Private Function GetAllWorkbooks() As Collection
    Dim id As GUID
    Dim hWnd As Long
    Dim hDesk As Long
    Dim hXL As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim app As Application
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set GetAllWorkbooks = New Collection

    'Define GUID values
    'hard codes IDispatch {00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    With id
        .Data1 = 132096
        .Data4(0) = 192
        .Data4(7) = 70
    End With

    'Loop through excel window handles to find applications
    hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Do While hWnd > 0
        hDesk = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        hXL = FindWindowEx(hDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hXL, &HFFFFFFF0, id, obj) = &H0 Then
            'Populate return collection with the workbooks
            Set app = obj.Application
            For Each wb In app.Workbooks
                GetAllWorkbooks.Add wb
            Next
        End If
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, hWnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Loop
End Function
```